# Updating database at a particular time

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm working on a project of an app that is deployed on Heroku and uses a PostgreSQL database. I was wondering how one updates the database at a prescribed time automatically.

I'm unsure whether I can do this directly via Postgres, if it is could one direct me to how to do it, or if I can directly write it from the code that I deploy to Heroku. The issue that I have with the latter is again I'm unsure how to tackle the problem. I'm using Python and it would be great if someone could point me to a useful library or data structure.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has no standard scheduler that allows to schedule jobs in the database. But many extensions exist like [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) for example. I don't know if you can install them on Heroku or maybe there is another preinstalled extension that has similar features: check with `\dx` or `select extname from pg_extension`.